# How to expose a container port outside of docker/container using docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, port, zeromq, pyzmq

I have a container that it has several ports, I want to have access to one of its ports (`9001`) outside of this docker as remote.

- My docker IP is: `172.17.0.1`
- My container IP is: `172.19.0.23`
- My server IP is: `192.168.1.131`

---

I have searched about that and I found `expose port` keyword, and I did it but not worked.

> How to expose docker ports to make your containers externally accessible
>   [Reference](https://bobcares.com/blog/docker-port-expose/)

---

## This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
      image: nginx:latest
      container_name: nginx
      ports:
        - "8010:8010"

      volumes:
        - .:/code
        - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

      links:
        - ivms

      restart: unless-stopped

  ivms:
      build: .
      container_name: ivms
      command: bash bashes/createDB.sh
      volumes:
        - .:/code
      expose:
        - "8010"
        - "9001"  # exposed disired port
      ports:
        - "9001:9001"
```

---

I run above docker-compose file with: `$ docker-compose up -d`

- But when I using **`server_IP:9001 --> 192.168.1.131:9001`** or
  **`docker_IP:9001 --> 172.17.0.1:9001`** can not access to that (in remote or local mode)
- But when using **`container_IP:9001 --> 172.19.0.23:9001`** this
  works in local.

What should I do that I can access to **`server_IP:9001 --> 192.168.1.131:9001`**?

---

[**NOTE**]:

- In `createDB.sh` runs several operations such as creating a **ZMQ on
  `9001` port**.
- I have been set the port allowing before, using `$ ufw allow 9001`
- I tried on Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu-Server 16.04

---

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried with `ports: ` instead `expose:`?

Comment: @mulg0r Yes, I tried with `port: - "9001:9001"` or using `9002` instead of `9001` using `port: - "9002:9001"` bot not worked.

Comment: Try with **ports**, not *port*

Comment: yes, did it. I mean was `ports`

Comment: Try with `network_mode: host` in docker compose services

Comment: I encountered with this error: `Cannot create container for service ivms: Conflicting options: host type networking can't be used with links. This would result in undefined behavior
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.`

Comment: What you're doing is definitely correct - it's not a matter of Docker/DockerCompose syntax. *Where* are you trying to access the IP from? The same machine, or a remote one? Also what OS are you running?

Comment: @Neekoy The same machine.

Comment: And what OS are you running?

Comment: @Neekoy I tried on ubuntu 16.04 and ubuntu-server 16.04

Comment: @BenyaminJafari Can you also add the content of bashes/createDB.sh to the OP?

Comment: @Neekoy question updated temporarily.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174706/discussion-between-benyamin-jafari-and-neekoy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved with below instruction:

In ZMQ app (in `ivms` container) I had used from the server IP to binding a connection as follow:

```
import zmq

if __name__ == '__main__':
    context = zmq.Context()
    socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
    socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, "")
    socket.bind("tcp://192.168.1.131:9001")  # doesn't work with server or docker IP

    while True:
        data = socket.recv_json()
```

It was working only as below:

```
socket.bind("tcp://192.168.1.131:9001")  # works, but can't access as remote
```

---

### Now I edited this line as the follows:

```
socket.bind("tcp://*:9001")  # Works both locally and remotely.
```

---

And this is my docker-compose.yml configuration:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
      image: nginx:latest
      container_name: nginx
      ports:
        - "8010:8010"

      volumes:
        - .:/code
        - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

      links:
        - ivms

      restart: unless-stopped

  ivms:
      build: .
      container_name: ivms
      command: bash bashes/createDB.sh
      volumes:
        - .:/code
      expose:
        - "8010"
      ports:
        - "9001:9001"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to actually map the port you should use

```
ivms:
  build: .
  container_name: ivms
  command: bash bashes/createDB.sh
  volumes:
    - .:/code
  ports:
    - "8010:8010"
    - "9001:9001"  # now you can access them locally
```

**warning you are using the same port for these two services ivms and nginx**

> The EXPOSE instruction informs Docker that the container listens on
>   the specified network ports at runtime. You can specify whether the
>   port listens on TCP or UDP, and the default is TCP if the protocol is
>   not specified.
>
> The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It
>   functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the
>   image and the person who runs the container, about which ports are
>   intended to be published.
>   -Docker Docs

Comment: I tried it already, but not worked, you can see in my question

Comment: do you mean of nginx port is `8010`?

Comment: You should remove the expose: part and just leave the ports: , but what I am not sure is why do you map nginx port 8010 and ivms also?

Comment: I did it, I remove expose and kept only ports, but not any changes. and about nginx, `ivms` app running a Django app on 8010 port and nginx get it, don't worry about nginX it works.

Comment: Is your container running? what can you see in the logs? can you docker exec into it?

Comment: Yes is run, and I can exec to `ivms` container. There isn't a specific logs about that. I think my question is relevant to docker-compose file expose or port or OS port mapping.

Comment: under the `ivms` remove de expose and leave the ports like "... - 9001:9001", change the command to `command: python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9001`. run docker-compose up and see if it appears something under localhost:9001 meaning your server IP